# Mixing getOrElse with forall

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I've defined a Option:

```
val names : Option[Seq[String]] = Option(Seq("Bob", "Alice", "Mike"))
names.get.forall(m => Seq("Bob").contains(m))
```

> Boolean = false

But, I would like to replace this with a **getOrElse** to avoid NPE. The following didn't work.

```
names.getOrElse.forall(m => Seq("Bob").contains(m))
```

> error: value forall is not a member of Object

Comment: sorry! fixed it now.

Comment: `names.fold(false)(_.forall(_ == "Bob"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to first `map` the sequence inside `Option` to a boolean value, and then `getOrElse` the final result, providing a default boolean value.

```
names.map(_.forall(m => Seq("Bob").contains(m))).getOrElse(false)
```

By the way, the inner lambda can also be abbreviated:

```
names.map(_.forall(Seq("Bob").contains)).getOrElse(false)
```

Comment: there is an unnecessary `Seq()` creation, you can use the `_ == "Whatever"`

Comment: @stsatlantis `_ == "Whatever"` does not scale to sequences that contain more than just a single element `"Whatever"`. But you are right that the *creation* of the sequence inside of the `forall` is unnecessary: that could have been done once outside of `forall`. And it should be a `HashSet` with `O(1)` lookup, not a `Seq`.

Comment: What I'm saying if s/he uses `Seq(only one element).contains` then it can be replaced with `_ == "Whatever"`

Answer (score 3):

Andrey Tyukin's answer is fine.

But you could also do the following, which is cool because it uses `exists` and `forall`. It's also shorter:

```
names.exists(_.forall(Seq(...).contains))
```

Comment: Note that in my answer I *assume* that the OP wants to return `false` if the option is `None`, I don't know for sure whether this is actually what OP wants. In my solution, it's easy enough to change the default value to `true`. In your code, one would have to use two `forall`s to get `true` by default. For some strange reason, most people find it difficult to understand that universal quantification of some predicate over an empty set always gives `true`.

Comment: If you want `true` as default, you need to use `forall` instead. But I agree that `getOrElse` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fold to get value from the option.

```
scala> names.map(_.forall(e => e.contains("Bob"))).fold(false)(identity)
res10: Boolean = false
```

Comment: You can move the fold before the map like @jwvh commented: names.fold(false)(_.forall(_ == "Bob"))

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as a `Seq[Seq[String]]` with  the following code

```
names.toList.flatten.contains("Bob")
```